# how to put searchBox inside gmaps?

Tags: javascript, html

i have problem.. i have canvas gmaps and i added some input-text for searching mark on gmaps canvas. The problem is this "input-text for searching" located outside the gmaps canvas, how to move "input-text for searching" inside the gmaps canvas?

here is the HTML and maps.JS

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group ">
   <input id="map-search" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" size="50%" >
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions, map, marker, searchBox, city,
        infoWindow = '',
        addressEl = document.querySelector( '#map-search' ),
        latEl = document.querySelector( '.latitude' ),
        longEl = document.querySelector( '.longitude' ),

        element = document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' );
    city = document.querySelector( '.reg-input-city' );

    if($('#latspan' ).val() == null){
        var latCar = -6.175350;
    } else { 
        var latCar =  $('#latspan').val();
    }

    if($('#lngspan').val() == null){
        var longCar = 106.827164;
    } else { 
        var longCar =  $('#lngspan').val();
    }

    mapOptions = {
        // How far the maps zooms in.
        zoom: 800,
        // Current Lat and Long position of the pin/

        center: new google.maps.LatLng( latCar, longCar ),
        // center : {
        //  lat: -34.397,
        //  lng: 150.644
        // },
        disableDefaultUI: false, // Disables the controls like zoom control on the map if set to true
        scrollWheel: true, // If set to false disables the scrolling on the map.
        draggable: true, // If set to false , you cannot move the map around.
        // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, // If set to HYBRID its between sat and ROADMAP, Can be set to SATELLITE as well.
        // maxZoom: 11, // Wont allow you to zoom more than this
        // minZoom: 9  // Wont allow you to go more up.

    };

    /**
     * Creates the map using google function google.maps.Map() by passing the id of canvas and
     * mapOptions object that we just created above as its parameters.
     *
     */
    // Create an object map with the constructor function Map()
    map = new google.maps.Map( element, mapOptions ); // Till this like of code it loads up the map.

    /**
     * Creates the marker on the map
     *
     */
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mapOptions.center,
        map: map,
        // icon: 'http://pngimages.net/sites/default/files/google-maps-png-image-70164.png',
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    /**
     * Creates a search box
     */
    searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox( addressEl );

    /**
     * When the place is changed on search box, it takes the marker to the searched location.
     */
    google.maps.event.addListener( searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces(),
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
            i, place, lat, long, resultArray,
            addresss = places[0].formatted_address;

        for( i = 0; place = places[i]; i++ ) {
            bounds.extend( place.geometry.location );
            marker.setPosition( place.geometry.location );  // Set marker position new.
        }

        map.fitBounds( bounds );  // Fit to the bound
        map.setZoom( 15 ); // This function sets the zoom to 15, meaning zooms to level 15.
        // console.log( map.getZoom() );

        lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
        long = marker.getPosition().lng();
        latEl.value = lat;
        longEl.value = long;

        resultArray =  places[0].address_components;

        // Get the city and set the city input value to the one selected
        for( var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++ ) {
            if ( resultArray[ i ].types[0] && 'administrative_area_level_2' === resultArray[ i ].types[0] ) {
                citi = resultArray[ i ].long_name;
                city.value = citi;
            }
        }

        // Closes the previous info window if it already exists
        if ( infoWindow ) {
            infoWindow.close();
        }
        /**
         * Creates the info Window at the top of the marker
         */
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: addresss
        });

        infoWindow.open( map, marker );
    } );


    /**
     * Finds the new position of the marker when the marker is dragged.
     */
    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, "dragend", function ( event ) {
        var lat, long, address, resultArray, citi;

        console.log( 'i am dragged' );
        lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
        long = marker.getPosition().lng();

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { latLng: marker.getPosition() }, function ( result, status ) {
            if ( 'OK' === status ) {  // This line can also be written like if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                address = result[0].formatted_address;
                resultArray =  result[0].address_components;

                // Get the city and set the city input value to the one selected
                // for( var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++ ) {
                //  if ( resultArray[ i ].types[0] && 'administrative_area_level_2' === resultArray[ i ].types[0] ) {
                //      citi = resultArray[ i ].long_name;
                //      console.log( citi );
                //      city.value = citi;
                //  }
                // }
                //addressEl.value = address;
                latEl.value = lat;
                longEl.value = long;

            } else {
                console.log( 'Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status );
            }

            // Closes the previous info window if it already exists
            if ( infoWindow ) {
                infoWindow.close();
            }

            /**
             * Creates the info Window at the top of the marker
             */
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: address
            });

            infoWindow.open( map, marker );
        } );
    });


}
```

Here is the picture on my gmaps canvas [pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq7Z6.jpg)

thank you for being willing to read this thread, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map.controls` with correct [position values](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning)

```
 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('map-search'));
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('map-search'));
```

Comment: thank you, its solved my problem sir... already browsing for a day and its my fault i'm not really understand about javascript